# What causes the error "undefined local variable or method `csv' for main:Object"?

Tags: ruby, rake

I am trying to write a rake task for importing a CSV file into multiple models. The code compiles without error, but I get this error message when I attempt to run it:

> rake aborted! NameError: undefined local variable or method `csv' for
>   main:Object
>   /Users/rickcasey/Projects/Programming/wfrails/lib/tasks/import_partial.rake:28:in`
>   block in '

Here is the script:

```
desc "Imports the  CSV file "
task :import_partial => :environment do

    require 'csv'    

    csv.foreach('public/partial.csv', :headers => true) do |row|

            # create records in independent tables

            # create the Company object
            this_company_name = row.to_hash.slice(*%w[county_name])
            if !(Company.exists?(company_name: this_company_name))
              Companies.create(row.to_hash.slice(*%w[company_name operator_num]))
            end
            thecompany = Company.find(this_company_name)
            company_id = thecompany.id

            # create the County object
            this_county_name = row.to_hash.slice(*%w[county])
            if !(County.exists?(county_name: this_county_name))
              Counties.create(county_name: this_county_name)
            end
            thecounty = County.find(this_county_name)
            county_id = thecounty.id

            # create the GasType object  
            this_gastype_name = row.to_hash.slice(*%w[gas_type])
            if !(GasType.exists?(gastype_name: this_gastype_name))
              GasType.create(gastype_name: this_gastype_name)
            end
            thegastype = GasType.find(this_gastype_name)
            gastype_id = thegastype.id


            # create the Field object
            this_field_name = row.to_hash.slice(*%w[field])
            if !(Field.exists?(field_name: this_field_name))
              Field.create(field_name: this_field_name, field_code: field_code)
            end
            thefield = Field.find(this_field_name)
            field_id = thefield.id

            # create the Formations object  
            this_formation_name = row.to_hash.slice(*%w[formation])
            if !(Formation.exists?(formation_name: this_formation_name))
              Counties.create(formation: this_formation_name, formation_code: formation_code)
            end
            theformation = Formation.find(this_formation_name)
            formation_id = theformation.id

            # debugging:
            puts "company_id:", company_id
            puts "county_id:", county_id
            puts "gastype_id:", gastype_id
            puts "field_id:", field_id
            puts "formation_id:", formation_id

            # create records in dependent tables:
            # Use the record id's from above independent table create records containing foreign keys:

            #Facilities.create(row.to_hash.slice(*%w[dir_e_w dir_n_s dist_e_w dist_n_s facility_name facility_num ground_elev lat long meridian qtrqtr range sec twp utm_x utm_y])

            #Wells.create(row.to_hash.slice(*%w[api_county_code api_seq_num first_prod_date form_status_date formation_status sidetrack_num spud_date status_date td_date test_date wbmeasdepth wbtvd well_bore_status well_name])


    end
end
```

My environment is: ruby 2.1.2p95, Rails 4.1.1

This is quite unclear, and have not found an example of similar error with an answer I understand yet....any help much appreciated!

Comment: At which line did the error occurred?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the error is in this line

```
csv.foreach('public/partial.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
```

It should be

```
CSV.foreach('public/partial.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the class name is uppercase - `CSV.foreach`, not `csv.foreach`.